# Trick to make SQL query do LIKE or = depending on bind variable?

Tags: sql-server-2005, oracle11g, sql-like

right now I have the following query in a stored procedure.

```
select * from table A where A.indexed_char_column LIKE :param1
```

:param1 can contain any type of wildcharacters, but sometimes it might not. '%abcdef%' usually wants a full table scan and 'abcdef' should do a index range scan. So I would like the SQL engine to use two different execution plans depending on this parameter.

Is there anyway I can make this behaviour possible? I would like answers for both Oracle 11gr2 and SQL Server 2005. I'm thinking if I could include a dummy parameter in the query (like a comment or something) that makes the SQL engine think of the  two queries, that are actually identical, not to be identical.

```
select /* use table scan */ * from table A where A.indexed_char_column LIKE :param1

select /* use index */ * from table A where A.indexed_char_column LIKE :param1
```

But I don't know how to accomplish this? Any other suggestions? Should I just use two stored procedures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the ability to change the hint/comment according to whether the value contains wildcards or not, why not change the **statement** instead?

```
if (contains wildcards) then
    select * from table A where A.indexed_char_column LIKE :param1;
else
    select * from table A where A.indexed_char_column = :param1;
```

Comment: These queries are huge! And they have several parameters which can (but might not) contain wildcards. To have these if/else stuff will make each procedure several pages long! But I think your solution is the best if the query is of a smaller kind :)

Comment: Often with queries that can have various parameters that might be wildcards, the best approach is to construct dynamic SQL based on the parameter values - while still using bind variables of course.

Answer (score 1):

For sql server you can use [table hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) or [query hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx) (look at OPTION RECOMPILE).  For either of those you'll probably have to be smart enough to know what hints to include in the query yourself.  I'm not sure what the oracle equivalents are.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server....
If you've done some testing and you're sure that it will benefit you to have two execution plans, then Joel's suggestion of OPTION (RECOMPILE) is the way to go.

However, if the index is narrow and selective, then it's probably best to use the index for the LIKE query as well as the equals query.

Conversely, if the index isn't very selective, then the equals query should probably just go straight for the table scan.

Comment: thanks for the reply. What's your definition of a narrow index? The indexes used in my queries are usually pretty selective. How do you figure it would be best to use the index for the LIKE query? If input parameter is 'abcdef%', then I would agree. '%abcdefg' then a full table scan should be better? Or maybe a full index scan can be used if all columns needed are present.

Comment: @KTrum - Narrow enough that the I/O is significantly lower to scan the index and lookup the table vs. scan the table. If the index includes all the columns needed then there's no need for the query to touch the table at all.